# Python-Tkinter: How do I update a whole segment?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a segment in my GUI that creates a varying number of labels using a for-loop.
Furthermore, I have a button that's supposed to delete all of these labels and recall the for loop with new information.

However, I can't figure out how to make my button do that. Specifically do both of these actions together.

I have tried to delete the frame containing the labels with frame.destroy() like this:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

def create():
    for i in 'test':
        tkinter.Label(frame, text='TEST').pack()
create()

def command():
    frame.destroy()
    # frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
    # frame.pack()
    create()

tkinter.Button(root, text='Button', command=command).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

That successfully deletes the labels but I can't figure out how to create new ones.

Same thing with putting the for-loop in a class and deleting the object and creating a new one.

Is there another option than deleting each individual label? I figure that would be rather complicated as each label would need an individual variable name.
Haven't tried that yet, tho.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `global frame` in each function so that they use the same variable:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

def create():
    global frame
    for i in 'test':
        tkinter.Label(frame, text='TEST').pack()
create()

def command():
    global frame
    frame.destroy()
    frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    create()

tkinter.Button(root, text='Button', command=command).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Since you just use `.pack()` the button moves to the top after, but this should work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Try this method:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Testing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.flag = True
        self.create()
        self.com_button()
        self.root.mainloop()


    def create(self):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        for n, i in enumerate('test'):
            tk.Label(self.frame, text='TEST').grid(row=n, column=0)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
    def command(self):
        if self.flag:
            self.frame.grid_forget()
            self.flag = False
        else:
            self.create()
            self.flag = True
    
    def com_button(self):
        tk.Button(self.root, text='Button', command=self.command).grid(row=1, column=0)

if __name__=='__main__':
    Testing()
```